# Convert Scala class object(having collections) into Json String

Tags: json, scala, gson

I am using `Gson` to serialize scala objects but this approach is only working for standard data types like **Int, String** but I'm not getting expected results with **collections** as below example:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

object Hello extends App {

  case class FilterJson(version: Int,
                        maps: Map[String, String],
                        gameModes: Map[String, String])

  def anyRefToJsonString(scalaValue: AnyRef): String = {
    import com.google.gson.Gson

    val gson = new Gson
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(scalaValue)
    jsonString
  } //End of function

  val finalJson = anyRefToJsonString(
    FilterJson(
      version = 6,
      maps = Map(
        "MP_ArcticFjord" -> "on"
      ),
      gameModes = Map(
        "Conquest" -> "on"
      )
    ))

  println(finalJson)
}
```

Above is the sample code in Scala but I'm getting **finalString** as 
follows:

```
{"version":6,"maps":{},"gameModes":{}}
```

but should have get this

```
{\"version\":6,\"maps\":{\"MP_ArcticFjord\":\"on\"},\"gameModes\":{\"Conquest\":\"on\"}}
```

Please help me on this i.e how to convert objects having **collections to Json String**

Comment: Do you *have* to use Gson or you can change the library?

Comment: I think this https://gist.github.com/raelg/e12d731ba01ba58f0006 might help you. If you "just" need Maps, you can use that MapSerializer.

Comment: You should use spray json it works fine it’s also easy to use just have to create the jsonFormater which is something like this val xyz =jsonFormatn(name of your case class) here n is the number of your case class parameter.